# Monopoly: Why is it this way?

Tags: monopoly

Is there any real-world reason why someone absolutely *has* to spend a night at a $2000 hotel when they have five dollars in their bank account, or is it just "the rules"?

Comment: What happened in October 1929 was that "rich" people stayed in hotels, the stock market crashed, they lost all their money (because they bought on "margin") and they jumped out of the hotel windows. Shortly afterward, there was a "joke" that when someone booked a hotel room, the clerk would ask him, "for sleeping or for jumping?

Answer (score 5):

Monopoly was originally designed as a game to show the [effects of capitalism](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20170728-monopoly-was-invented-to-demonstrate-the-evils-of-capitalism). But the people liked the collection of money and the suffering of their fellow players too much so the original purpose was soon lost.

The game is a model of a subset of reality. So yes it needs rules. They may seem unfair, but real life can be a bit less optimal. And at least with this game, you can flip the board, curse at your (obviously cheating) little brother and storm out of the room. Real life has some limitations on that.

Comment: Although I generally like the answer you gave, I believe you should review your language. 
Have you consider to also attach some links backing up your points? That would help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

An obvious real-world reason is that hotels charge you for your stay whether you have the $2K or not.

The actual site of breaking the "real world" connection is that a (reasonable) person with $5 in the bank would stay home, yet the person locked in the body of a top hat or scottie dog is not permitted that option on the game board.

These sorts of concessions are part and parcel of board games. The simplification of the simulation is needed for the game to be both rigorously defined and still playable.